# Could not locate OpenAL library Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Решил попробовать разобраться в libGDX, запустил десктопную версию и у меня вылезла такая ошибка:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not locate OpenAL library.
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:156)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:86)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:67)
    at com.yuta.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:13)
```

Магия гугла не выдала ничего, что связано с Android Studio

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. В моём случае ошибка возникла из-за того, что имя пользователя Windows написано кириллицей ("Максим"). Помогло создание альтернативного пользователя "seconduser" и соответствующей установки свойства **user.name**.

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        System.setProperty("user.name","seconduser");
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdx1(), config);
    }
}
```

Ошибка описана здесь: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233342

Answer (score 2):

Решил эту же проблему без создания нового пользователя так:

1. Вбил своё имя пользователя в верхнее поле `UTF-8-decoded` [тут](http://mothereff.in/utf-8)
2. Скопировал получившуюся абракадабру из нижнего поля `UTF-8-encoded`
3. Добавил в начало main метода строчку `System.setProperty("user.name","абракадабра");`

Answer (score 2):

Еще проще без создания нового юзера и перевода абракадабры:

```
System.setProperty("user.name","Public");
```

Потому, как пользователь Public есть у всех.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно работает. Очень выручили!!!

Answer (score 0):

Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой, в итоге оказалось, что проблема в имени пользователяЮ оно было задано кирилицей. Исправил, и дописал в main:

```
 System.setProperty("user.name","your new name in Latin");
```

Ошибка ушла.

Comment: Чем Ваш ответ отличается от ответов данных ранее?